# Add new registration form magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, customer-account, customer-group

i want to  create a new registration form for wholesaler  the form should be same as new customer registration form which is provided by magento.when i register wholesaler customer data should be save in same table as new customer registration data is stored the only difference is that **groupid should be stored as "2" in table**  below is the form image which is provided by magento i want same form for wholesaler.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create wholesalerregistration.phtml file

```
app\code\vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\wholesalerregistration.phtml

<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.extra') ?>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create info">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Personal Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name')->setObject($block->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($block->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>
            <div class="field choice newsletter">
                <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if ($block->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox">
                <label for="is_subscribed" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign Up for Newsletter')) ?></span></label>
            </div>
            <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter') ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!-- group_id -->

        <?php /* in value write your wholesaler id */ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="2">
        <!-- end group_id -->

        <?php $_dob = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Dob') ?>
        <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_taxvat = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Taxvat') ?>
        <?php if ($_taxvat->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_taxvat->setTaxvat($block->getFormData()->getTaxvat())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php $_gender = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Gender') ?>
        <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_gender->setGender($block->getFormData()->getGender())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <fieldset class="fieldset address">
            <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />

            <?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company') ?>
            <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone') ?>
            <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getFormData()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax') ?>
            <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
                <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getFormData()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>

            <div class="field street required">
                <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Street Address')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address')) ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                    <div class="nested">
                        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                            <div class="field additional">
                                <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i)) ?>" id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label for="city" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field region required">
                <label for="region_id" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('State/Province')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                        <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select a region, state or province.')) ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('State/Province')) ?>" class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region')) ?>" style="display:none;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field zip required">
                <label for="zip" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field country required">
                <label for="country" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Country')) ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes');?>
            <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]');?>
                <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address');?>
                <?= $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        </fieldset>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sign-in Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field password required">
            <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                       class="input-text"
                       data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                       data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                       autocomplete="off">
                <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                    <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                        <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Create an Account')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create an Account')) ?></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?= /* @noEscape */ $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null' ?>;

    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
<?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all') ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getFormData()->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $this->helper(\Magento\Directory\Helper\Data::class)->getCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2. Create layout file (Like wholesalerregistration_index_index.xml)

```
app\code\vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\wholesalerregistration_index_index.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="wholesalerregistration_index_index" template="vendor_Module::wholesalerregistration.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Create events.xml

```
app\code\vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="save_customer_group" instance="vendor\Module\Observer\SaveCustomerGroupId" />
    </event>
</config>
```

4. Create SaveCustomerGroupId.php file

```
app\code\vendor\Module\Observer\SaveCustomerGroupId

namespace vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;

Class SaveCustomerGroupId implements ObserverInterface {
    public $_customerRepositoryInterface;
    public $_messageManager;
    public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
            ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
       $accountController = $observer->getAccountController();
       $request = $accountController->getRequest();
       $group_id = $request->getParam('group_id');

       try {
           /*$customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
           $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);*/
           $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();           
           $customer->setGroupId($group_id);
           $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

       } catch (Exception $e){
           $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Something went wrong! Please try again.'));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can You please explain me  where your are setting group id 2 the logic behind setting that group id value  to "2 " which is a  wholesaler groupid

Comment: You can fine wholesaler group id from magento admin (Backend) in customer => Customer Groups. [https://prnt.sc/mw89zz]. Or you can also create your own cutomer group.

Comment: That i get it   my question is how it gets id in observer

Comment: You can see my code. I have add one hidden field and write wholesaler group id. https://prnt.sc/mw8fwy

Comment: in observer execute method $accountController = $observer->getAccountController();
       $request = $accountController->getRequest(); this two lines are written can you please explain what kind of data is coming $accountcontroller and $request

Comment: Here get form post data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90857/discussion-between-harsh-jayswal-and-sweety-masmiya).

Comment: @HarshJayswal in my case  <?= $_dob->setDate($block->getFormData()->getDob())->toHtml() ?> is not working. Its gives only a text box and no select date button

Comment: @Nafisa have you got this working? i am trying to do a select

Answer (score 0):

He is using in form input hidden field as

```
<!-- group_id -->

    <?php /* in value write your wholesaler id */ ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="2">
    <!-- end group_id -->
```

and for backend

```
try {
       /*$customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
       $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);*/
       $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();           
       $customer->setGroupId($group_id);
       $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

   }
```

Comment: my only question is how it gets id in observer

Comment: For customer ID use

 $customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();

Answer (score 0):

For customer ID use

```
 $customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
```

To get groups:(on single registeration page)

```
<?php $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('NPath to\Block\CustomerGroups');
$groups = $blockObj->getCustomerGroup();
?>
<div class="field group_id required">
<label for="group_id" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('I want to register as') ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
<select name="group_id">
<?php foreach ($groups as $key => $data) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['label'] ?>"</option>
 <?php } ?>
</select> </div></div>
```

To manually set id on registration:

```
try {

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        $customer->setData('group_id', 2); // or whatever the group id should be
        $customer->save();

    } catch ( Exception $e ) {}
```